# How to extract the next line after a specific keyword when there are words in between using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract the amount 495.65 after matching the keyword total. The amount is in next line. Thanks in advance!

Total :(Dirham Four Hundred Ninety Six and Sixty Five fils Only)

496.65

Best Regards,
y approve the proposal and arrange the payment, accordingly we will provide you the tax
invoice .

```
    re.findall('(?<=total :)((.*){2})', string, re.IGNORECASE)
```

The output is: (Dirham Four Hundred Ninety Six and Sixty Five fils Only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match `total :` and capture the value in a group by matching 1 or more newlines after matching the rest of the line.

```
\bTotal :.*[\r\n]+(\d+(?:\.\d+))\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\bTotal :.*` Match `total :` and the rest of the line
- `[\r\n]+` Match 1+ newlines
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+))` Capture group 1, match a digit with an optional decimal part
- `\b` A word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qboFzL/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/KRqaaW)

**Example code**

```
import re

regex = r"\bTotal :.*[\r\n]+(\d+(?:\.\d+))\b"

test_str = ("Total :(Dirham Four Hundred Ninety Six and Sixty Five fils Only)\n\n"
    "496.65\n\n"
    "Best Regards,\n"
    "y approve the proposal and arrange the payment, accordingly we will provide you the tax\n"
    "invoice .")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.IGNORECASE))
```

**Output**

```
['496.65']
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. What if the amount (number) is in third line and the amount in words is in second line? How can the amount be extracted in this case?

Comment: @M_Arora You might do it like this `\bTotal :.*\r?\n\(.*\)\r?\n(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\b` https://regex101.com/r/VGi0wD/1 or like this matching all lines after total: that do not start with a digit, and then capture the amount when it does start with a digit and optional decimal part `\bTotal :.*(?:\r?\n(?!\d).*)*\r?\n(\d+(?:\.\d+))\b` https://regex101.com/r/N7F9Dj/1